# Converting a Spring Boot JAR Application to a WAR

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have tried to run "Converting a Spring Boot JAR Application to a WAR" application by converting into a war package as instructed...and since it was mentioned that  void main() is no longer needed,I removed it and tried to build it using gradle but it throws error **unable to find main class.**

### The content of  class after my modification is as below

```
Application.java

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

}
```

---

what is the mistake am I making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want an executable war then remove the Spring Boot plugin. If you do, leave it in, and keep the main().

Comment: So If I keep the spring boot plug in then main is mandatory because the plug in searches for a main rught?

Comment: Yes, the main function of the plugin is to turn a vanilla archive into an executable one. You can't do that without a main.